# TypeScript Application not finding local.env file

Tags: typescript, environment-variables, config

I have inherited an application that currently does not run locally. I believe the issue is that it cannot find the environment variables.

My launch.json looks like this:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Chat Web Server",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\dist\\server.js",
      "preLaunchTask": "npm build",
      "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}\\Env\\Local.env",
      "runtimeArgs": ["--inspect=127.0.0.1:9264"], // , "-r", "dotenv/config"
      "sourceMaps": true
    }
  ]
}
```

When running the application I get an error from this constructor

```
public constructor(Topic: string) {
  this.Topic = Topic;
  console.log("Service Bus Connection String");
  console.log(process.env.ServiceBusUri );
  this.Client = ServiceBusClient.createFromConnectionString(
    process.env.ServiceBusUri || ""
  );
  this.SenderClient = this.Client.createTopicClient(Topic);
  this.Sender = this.SenderClient.createSender();
}
```

> TypeError: Missing Endpoint in Connection String.
> at Object.create (C:_Development\xxx\node_modules@azure\amqp-common\dist\index.js:1564:19)
> at Function.createFromConnectionString (~\node_modules@azure\service-bus\dist\index.js:6281:52)
> at new ServiceBus (C:_Development\xxx\dist\Lib\Utils\ServiceBus.js:44:54)
> at Object. (C:_Development\xxx\dist\server.js:50:26)

There is a value in local.env

ServiceBusUri=Endpoint=sb://xxxxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz=

When outputting this to the console the value of `process.env.ServiceBusUri` is undefined.

I have limited knowledge of TypeScript and how I should reference the file but this is how the folder structure appears

Any help on what I need to do to get the values read correctly will be very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you check if `dotenv` package is installed and if there is a call to it somewhere at the entry point of your application (like `require('dotenv').config()`). If not, the env file will probably never be read.

Comment: @FabianStrathaus, doing a global search of the application I see this in a lib file require('dotenv').config({path: path.resolve(os.homedir(), '.env.twitter')});  I am guessing I need something similar elsewhere?

Comment: @FabianStrathaus we have this deployed in azure as an app service and the config values are read perfectly fine. Its just the local.env file I have issue with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to read local `.env` files, you should use `dotenv` package provided from npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

You should then, right at the beginning of your application, include the following code:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: '/custom/path/to/Env/Local.env' })
```

Of course you can make this code depending on your current environment by using an `if` statement to check `process.env`. This way no environment variables used in production would be overwritten. The reason this code works in azure is probably that the environment variables used are injected by azure itself.

After that the values should be available during runtime like implemented (e.g. `process.env.ServiceBusUri`).